# Can I still use paladin Danse?

Tags: fallout-4

So I have just finished Blind Betrayal for the Brotherhood of Steel story arc. I chose to defend Danse. I passed all the charisma checks and everything. Even left Elder Manson alive. However, whenever I try to talk to him to get him as a companion he acts like a normal NPC. Will I ever be able to use him again? How do I get him back as a companion?

Answer (score 1):

I fear you may have run into a bug with Danse, or at some point may have become hostile with the Brotherhood.  According to [the Wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Danse), there are two bugs that could potentially happen with Danse:

> - If he is alive after Blind Betrayal and the Survivor becomes an enemy of the Brotherhood of Steel, then a bug may occur rendering him unable to react to the player character.
>
>   - If Blind Betrayal has been completed, he may instead ignore the Sole Survivor and will only turn hostile if attacked. This appears to be a bug since the player character can still open the trade menu with him. The issue effectively removes him as a companion, but will not remove his perk.
>   - Danse will stop talking and functioning as a companion if the player becomes hostile with the Brotherhood, even after Blind Betrayal's completion. This is evident by the fact that he is killable and functions more like a normal settler than a companion.

I would try to reload your game to a point before you've completed that quest, and see if the outcome changes.  The Wiki also says that after the quest, if you have him as a companion, the Brotherhood will be hostile towards you.  I'm wondering if this may have happened to you and now Danse is bugged.